# How to see restore history of a deleted database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

For example, I had a database and I want to see which physical backup file was used to restore into it. The problem is that the database was deleted. How can I see the record?

Comment: Do a search for the files with the extensions which are mentioned [here](https://sqlbak.com/blog/sql-server-backup-bak-vs-sqb). If the database has been deleted, then you're going to find it difficult to find any of its parameters. Are there any other databases on the same server which could perhaps give you a clue? p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: If the msdb backuphistory still exists, try `SELECT bmf.physical_device_name
FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory AS rh
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset AS bs ON bs.backup_set_id = rh.backup_set_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS bmf ON bmf.media_set_id = bs.media_set_id
WHERE rh.destination_database_name = N'YourDroppedDatabase';`

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the database was dropped, your luck will vary considerably.

If the database was dropped simply by using the `DROP DATABASE` command, then the restore history will be available to you.

However, if the database was dropped via the SSMS GUI after the restore, then you may be out of luck. In SSMS, the default is to select the option for "Delete backup and restore history information for databases". When this option is selected, the backup & restore history for the dropped database(s) will be removed from msdb:
[image: SSMS Drop Database GUI]

However, if you either *uncheck* that box, or do the drop from T-SQL, then your backup & restore history will be available.

```
CREATE DATABASE Floop;
BACKUP DATABASE Floop TO DISK = 'C:\temp\Floop.bak' WITH INIT;
RESTORE DATABASE Floop FROM DISK = 'C:\temp\Floop.bak' WITH REPLACE;
DROP DATABASE Floop;
```

To see the restore history, simply query `msdb.dbo.restorehistory`:

```
SELECT *
FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory
WHERE destination_database_name = 'Floop';
```

The details of the restorehistory table are [available in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/restorehistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Essentially, it contains the database that was restored, information about who restored it, the type of restore, and the restore point.

If you want information about the *backup* that was restored, you can join to other backup tables. When a database from a different instance is restore, SQL Server copies the backup information from the backup header in the file into the backup tables.

```
SELECT 
        RestoreDate = rh.restore_date,
        RestoredDb  = rh.destination_database_name,
        RestoreUser = rh.[user_name],
        RestoreType = rh.restore_type,
        ReplaceDb   = rh.[replace],
        RecoverDb   = rh.[recovery],
        BackupSourceServer  = bh.machine_name,
        BackupSourceDb      = bh.database_name,
        BackupFinishDate    = bh.backup_finish_date,
        BackupFile          = bmf.physical_device_name
FROM msdb.dbo.restorehistory    AS rh
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset         AS bh  ON bh.backup_set_id = rh.backup_set_id
JOIN msdb.dbo.backupmediafamily AS bmf ON bmf.media_set_id = bh.media_set_id
WHERE rh.destination_database_name = 'Floop';
```

Comment: yea that checkbox was checked out when dropping the db :( oh well

Comment: Yeahhhhhh. I *detest* that default.

Comment: You could always restore the `msdb` database (that contains the restore history) to say `msdb_restore` (and `MOVE` files) and query the restore / backup history from that database. Sorry for the late hint.